# Scale of a prefab is getting back to what was in original

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've a problem, 
In orthello package I've created sprite atlas and imported sprites into it. Then I've created prefabs from those sprites and I've changed the scale of those sprites in the prefab. Unfortunately, when I put this prefab into scene that old scale is being restored. Any thoughts?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Comment: Great, but "unity3d" makes people think the product is called Unity3D (even the tag's description makes that mistake, so it was probably created by someone who didn't know what to actually name the tag).  You make a better tag!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problam with auto-restoring variables in scripts. And I suggest do same what I did. Attatch to prefab script which in Start or Awake function sets wanted scale.